# Ettercap not compiling

Tags: c, cmake

I'm trying to compile Ettercap on windows using CMake, but I get the following errors:

```
CMake Error at interfaces/CMakeLists.txt:104 (set_target_properties):
  set_target_properties called with incorrect number of arguments.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:207 (set_target_properties):
  set_target_properties called with incorrect number of arguments.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:229 (set_target_properties):
  set_target_properties called with incorrect number of arguments.
```

The lines that cause the errors are the following:

```
set_target_properties(ec_interfaces PROPERTIES
  ENABLE_EXPORTS On
  POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON
  #  LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES ""
  OUTPUT_NAME ettercap-ui
  VERSION ${VERSION}
  SOVERSION 0
  )
```

```
    set_target_properties(ettercap PROPERTIES
    INSTALL_RPATH ${INSTALL_LIBDIR})
```

```
set_target_properties(lib_ettercap PROPERTIES
  ENABLE_EXPORTS On
  #  LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES ""
  OUTPUT_NAME ettercap
  VERSION ${VERSION}
  SOVERSION 0
  )
```

I'm new to CMake, so I have no idea how to fix this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does VERSION have a value? You can test it with `message("VERSION:${VERSION")`. Same for `INSTALL_LIBDIR`

Comment: @Devolus they seem to be empty. Should I just take the lazy route and hardcode them?

Comment: That may be one solution. Or you have to find out, where these values should come from. That depends on your requirements. I would hardcode it and see if everything works. You can still figure out the correct values once you know that there are no other problems.